# Check if  app has been purchased

Tags: iphone

I am a beginner; I am trying to solve this but am unable to do so.

I have created an app that displays a few options in a table. When the user taps the cell the details of selected option is shown on another page (details are stored in a plist file).

What I want to do is to set it up so that if the user has purchased the app then only the details should be visible, but if the user has not purchased it, the user should be prompted to do so.

I have created a product ID for iTunes Connect and also created a testing account to test the app.

My problem is with the code: how should i check if user has already made the purchase?

Answer (score 2):

Using NSUserDefaults is the easiest solution.

After a successful purchase:

> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>   setObject:@"purchased"
>   forKey:@"myPaidItem"];
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>   synchronize];

And when you need to check if the user has purchased the item:

> NSString* isPurchased =
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
>   stringForKey:@"myPaidItem"];
>
> if ([@"purchased"
>   compare:isPurchased]==NSOrderedSame) {
>   ........ }

Hope that helps

Comment: if that's the correct answer to your question, I'd appreciate marking as such

Comment: A question: if the user decides to uninstall the app and install it again, he will have to repurchase the payed item right?

Comment: Yes, he needs to purchase the item again, though he won't be charged for the purchase. An alert pops up and says "You have already purchased this item, do you want to download it now?" and the process continues as if he purchased it (if your in-app purchase is non-expiring)

Answer (score 0):

you have to store this information in appContext as a bool if the transaction is OK , boo= true 
and when he want to buy another time you hve to check the value of boo wich is stored in app Context